# Infinite, Odd Möbius Strip

Tags: general-topology

I have never delved into the realm of topology, or into anything remotely close to this, but I'm a curious outsider:

The standard Möbius strip is "rotated" a single time (there is probably some proper terminology for this?); I'm assuming here that Möbius strips are created with an odd number of rotations.

How would a Möbius strip of infinite, though always odd, rotations function compared to finite rotations? 
Perhaps if it were assumed that the length of given material is not allowed to be extended, the structure would collapse into a point or become an infinitely thin line-type circle (would convergence/divergence come into play)?

Comment: What you mean by "rotated a single time" is usually denoted as a half twist. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip.

Answer (score 1):

The Möbius strip $M$ is a well-defined topological space which can be obtained as a quotient space of the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ by identifying the points $(0,t)$ and $(1,1-t)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. If you think of a strip of paper, then you glue its end interval by a half twist.

The Möbius strip has many embeddings into $\mathbb R^3$. That is, there are many subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ which are homeomorphic to $M$. These may look very different at first glance although they are topologically identical.

The "usual paper model" is certainly the simplest way to embed $M$ into $\mathbb R^3$. But you can make other paper models of $M$ having an odd number of half twists.

However, there is no "paper model" with "infinititely many, though always an odd number, of half twists".

First it is a logical issue: It does not make any sense to make an infinite but **odd** number of half twists.

But perhaps one could understand the desired embedding as some sort of "limit" of  models with an odd number $2k+1$ of half twists as $k \to \infty$? It is difficult to grasp what this should mean. So let us show heuristically that it does not work. Each half twist of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ needs some part $[a,b] \times [0,1]$ with $0 \le a < b \le 1$. If we want to perform infinitely many half twists, then we would need infinitely many disjoint parts $[a_n,b_n] \times [0,1]$ such that $d_n = b_n -a_n \to  0$ as $n \to \infty$ . The $b_n$ have a supremum $b \in [0,1]$, so the intervals $[a_n,b_n]$ cluster at $b$. Via the embeding the sets $M_c = \{c\} \times [0,1]$ are identified with line segments $L_c \subset \mathbb R^3$. Their lengths must have a lower bound $r > 0$. Otherwise the embedding would collapse some $M_c$ to a point which is nonsense. But now close to $b$ we make infinitely half twists, thus the system of line segments $L_c$ of length $\ge r$ rotates infinitely many as $c \to b$. Thus the endpoints describe two infinite helices on the surface of some sort of tube around a circle. It is clear that all points of $L_c$ are cluster points of these helices, thus the embedding of $M$ cannot be continuous because the endpoints of the $L_c$ have to approach endpoints of $L_b$.